# Flask, how to return a success status code for ajax call

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask

On the server-side, I am just printing out the json-as-dictionary to the console

```
@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        print request.json.keys()
    return "hello world"
```

Now, whenever I make a post request via ajax, the console prints out the dictionary with the contents I need.

On the client-side, I have been trying to use various methods to execute some jquery based on a successfull ajax call. I just realized that this might be an error on my server-side, i.e I am not sending any request header to tell jquery that its ajax call was a success.

So how do I send an OK status back to my client to tell it everything is all right?

For the sake of completeness, here is my clientside code

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(myData),
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/',
    success: function () {
        console.log("This is never getting printed!!")
    }});
```

Comment: Have you tried returning a valid JSON string instead of the plain text `hello world`? You specify the return data type is json, but jquery probably can't decode "hello world" so the success function is never called.

Comment: @PeterGibson the "hello world" is being returned on a GET request. I am not returning anything on POST.

Comment: @PeterGibson that was indeed the problem. I put a  `return 'OK'` and its working now. You can submit an answer if you like.

Comment: Oh right sorry - still without a return value, Python defaults to returning `None` which is not a valid JSON object. Try returning something like `'{"hello": "world"}'`

Comment: Okay great :) I see now that `dataType` is probably for the post data.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

[About Responses](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#about-responses) in Flask:

> ## About Responses
>
> The return value from a view function is automatically converted into a response object for you. If the return value is a string it's converted into a response object with the string as response body, a `200 OK` status code and a `text/html` mimetype. The logic that Flask applies to converting return values into response objects is as follows:
>
> 1. If a response object of the correct type is returned it's directly returned from the view.
> 2. If it's a string, a response object is created with that data and the default parameters.
> 3. If a tuple is returned the items in the tuple can provide extra information. Such tuples have to be in the form `(response, status, headers)` or `(response, headers)` where at least one item has to be in the tuple. The `status` value will override the status code and `headers` can be a list or dictionary of additional header values.
> 4. If none of that works, Flask will assume the return value is a valid WSGI application and convert that into a response object.

So, if you return text string (as you are doing), the status code that your AJAX call has to receive is `200 OK`, and your success callback must be executing. However, I recommend you to return a JSON formatted response like:

```
return json.dumps({'success':True}), 200, {'ContentType':'application/json'}
```

Answer (score 61):

As an option to [aabilio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26080784/4375397), you can use the jsonify method in Flask which automatically sets the Content-Type:

```
from flask import jsonify

resp = jsonify(success=True)
return resp
```

You can (optionally) set the response code explicitly:

```
resp.status_code = 200
```

Comment: And even simpler: `return {}`

Answer (score 15):

In addition to the answers already posted, I find using the [`make_response`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.make_response) method in Flask (from version 0.6) to be a clearer alternative especially when you need to return status codes with the response JSON for APIs from Flask:

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, make_response

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/do_thing')
def do_thing():
    # ... other code ...
    data = {'message': 'Done', 'code': 'SUCCESS'}
    return make_response(jsonify(data), 201)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Also, this approach allows you to pass a response code (201) and will automatically set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`.

Answer (score 8):

In newer versions of flask, it'll handle conversions in the response for you now. Your response can be simplified to returning your dictionary and response code like this:

```py
@app.route("/my_route")
def my_route():
    data = {"status": "success", "some key", "some value"}
    return data, 200
```

`data` doesn't necessarily need to be a dictionary either, you could also pass in a string too!

Comment: Thanks, the easiest way

Answer (score 1):

When returning a response using `jsonify` just add the `status_code` as the second parameter of the `return`.  I've used `jsonify` in this admin_required decorator with the 401 unauthorized HTTP code. Example:

```
return jsonify({'error': 'Admin access is required'}), 401
```

Full example:

```
def admin_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        if current_user and hasattr(current_user, 'user_type') and current_user.user_type == 'admin':
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            if '/api/' in request.url_rule.rule:
                return jsonify({'error': 'Admin access is required'}), 401

            flash(_('Admin access required'))
            return redirect(url_for('main.public_index'))

    return decorated
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [response_class](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.response_class) together with the json dump. Check the example below:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route(/info)
def getInfo():
    response = app.response_class(
            response=json.dumps({"status":"success","code":0,"data":{"Name":"Eyong","Age":30}}),
            status=200,
            mimetype='application/json'
    )
    return response
```